# Exporting table/view definitions for sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, migration, export

I'm trying to migrate some database tables from one SQLServer2005 instance to another, by first creating the tables/views on the new server, then re-running some data import scripts.

What's an easy way to quickly get the CREATE TABLE and CREATE VIEW statements for some tables/views on the old server? Or is there another, easier way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the SQL Management Studio you can use the [Generate Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078.aspx) functionality to generate an SQL script to create some or all of the objects in the database, suitable for execution on another server.